# ERROR 000539: NameError: name 'prevX' is not defined

Tags: field-calculator, arcgis-pro, python-parser, error-000539

I'm trying to use the field calculator to input data into a field that I previously created, but it keeps saying that prevX is not defined in line 9. I'm very new to python and I don't really understand what's going on. This is my input into the code block

```py
import math
def PtDistance(FID, Xval,Yval):
    global prevY
    global prevX
    if(FID == 1):
        prevX, prevY = Xval, Yval
        dist = 0
    else:
        dist = math.sqrt((prevX-Xval)**2+(prevY-Yval)**2)
        prevX, prevY = Xval, Yval
    return(dist)
```

and this is the error I keep getting

```
ERROR 000539: Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "< expression >", line 1, in <module>  
  File "< string >", line 9, in PtDistance  
NameError: name 'prevX' is not defined
```

Why is only line 9 the problem and not line 6 as well?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  What is your Field Calculator expression preceding that code block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define an intial value for `prevX` (and for `prevY`) before you use them in a calculation.  Otherwise, the first time the code tries to read their value, it fails.

This cannot occur on line 6, because you're not using them as part of a calculation there (just assigning a value to them).

Additionally, there is no `prevX` (or `prevY`) defined in the global scope (outside of the function definition.

The two extra lines in the code below should resolve both of these issues.

There is also some other issues with the code.  It look as though your planning to use `FID==1` to initialise `prevX` and `prevY`.  However, you should never rely on the order of the records being what you want it to be in database transactions.

I would explicitly set these values to NULL (`None` in Python), and check for this instead.  This would make it:

```
import math

#  Add these two extra lines here to create and initialise global variables
prevX = None
prevY = None

def PtDistance(FID, Xval,Yval):
    global prevY
    global prevX
    #  Change this line to check for NULLs (None)
    if prevX is None or prevY is None:
        prevX, prevY = Xval, Yval
        dist = 0
    else:
        dist = math.sqrt((prevX-Xval)**2+(prevY-Yval)**2)
        prevX, prevY = Xval, Yval
    return(dist)
```

(Of course, this assumes that your `Xval` and `Yval` parameters are not ever going to be passed in as NULLs.  IF they could be NULL, there are other options for handling the situation.)